# How to re-bind a specific div to allow scroll

Tags: jquery

On our website, we have an overlay that pops up when alerts or other pop-up divs are displayed on the screen. When this overlay is added, we remove the scroll with

```
 $('html,body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

However, there is a specific overlay that has an inner `<div>` that is large enough that we want to allow scrolling. The scroll bar is in the div correctly, but the mousewheel does not work because of the line above. Is there a way to re-add the binding to scroll using the mousewheel on just the div I want and not the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the event target first, if it is the element that you still want to let scroll dont do the `preventDefault` call

```
$('html,body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("#someDiv") ) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
// To also check children
$('html,body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("#someDiv") || 
           $(event.target).closest("#someDiv").length == 1  ) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you scroll past the top or bottom of the div though this will end up scrolling the page still. There is a trick of putting a css style of `overflow:hidden` on the html/body to prevent scroll of the actual page

```
function onDisplayPopup(){
    $("html,body").css({overflow:"hidden"});
}
```

Comment: That "sort of" worked.. Now, I can scroll if I am hovered over the div I want to scroll, but ONLY that div, if I hover over a child element of the div, then it stops. Also, the scroll affects the HTML, Body scroll bar as well

Comment: Ok after your edit I can fix my 2nd problem. What about the whole children thing?

Comment: For the children you can use the jQuery method `.closest` to see if its a child of `#someDiv` will edit to show that

Comment: That last part helped! However, are you sure you want `css({ display: "hidden" })` on pop up? That didn't seem to work either

Comment: Yea that is a typo meant overflow